# Electric field of charged sphere only by superposing fields created by loops

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, electric-circuits, electric-fields

I am trying to find an alternative way of calculating the electric field inside and outside of a sphere with charge density σ, all of it in its surface. The sphere has a radius R.

I am trying to fin this field (inside and outside) by superposing the electric field of several circular loops.

Do you have any idea how to tackle this? I can't seem to find a way to start solving it (thank God Gauss' law exists, btw :) )

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

How do you envisage your "circular loops"?

If a sphere's major axis is the x axis, are the "circular loops" concentric with the x axis and ranging from x=-R to x=+R?

If so, compute the charge on each elemental  "loop" $ d\sigma $ and integrate using Coulomb's law.  Exploit symmetry of  course.

Answer (score 0):

You should try it by cutting the sphere into circular rings along the axis joining the point where you want to find the field and the centre of the sphere